# Google Earth Engine_Python code error (Post-2)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, folium

I am confused by this error. I had written it on Anaconda and I am trying to run the script on GEE. I started and closed the second parentheses but the error persists. Rectify my error as I am new to this.

Where am I wrong?

**CODE:**

```
collection20 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_SO2').select('SO2_column_number_density').filterDate('2020-03-23', '2020-05-31').mean()
collection19 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_SO2').select('SO2_column_number_density').filterDate('2019-03-23', '2019-05-31').mean()

mask = collection20.lt(-0.001)
mask_ = collection20.gt(-0.001)
value = 0.0
collection20 = mask.multiply(value).add(collection20.multiply(mask_))

mask = collection19.lt(0)
mask_ = collection19.gt(0)
value = 0.0
collection19 = mask.multiply(value).add(collection19.multiply(mask_))


no2_diff = collection19.subtract(collection20)
no2_diff = no2_diff.divide(collection19).multiply(100)

roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([60, 5, 98.5+5, 37])
band_viz =
#The issue is here
{
 'min': -75,
 'max': 75, 
 'palette' : ['yellow', 'orange', 'red']
  }: 
 { 'palette' : ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
}
colormap = cm.LinearColormap(['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'], vmin=-75, vmax=75)
#colormap = cm.linear.YlOrRd_09.scale(0, 0.0002).to_step(10)
colormap.caption = '% change in column number density'
no2_diff = collection19.subtract(collection20)
no2_diff = no2_diff.divide(collection19).multiply(100)
mapid = no2_diff.clip(roi).getMapId(band_viz)

map = folium.Map(location=[24.11,75.27+5],zoom_start=4, height=550,width=600)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `band_viz` dictionary has the wrong syntax. You have a misplaced `:` on line 23.

I am unsure why you have 2 references to `palette`, but the dictionary notation should be:

```py
band_viz = {
 'min': -75,
 'max': 75, 
 'palette' : ['yellow', 'orange', 'red']
}
```

You can change the above colour list for

```py
['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
```

if that is what you need.